# DBNull throwing up an error

Tags: asp.net

I'm checking to see if DBNull occurs.

C# Code:

```
tbDuration.Text = (string)MyReader["TDuration"]==DBNull?"":(string)MyReader["TDuration"];
```

But I get an error on DBNull:

> Error  4   'System.DBNull' is a 'type' but is used like a 'variable'   C:\Visual Studio

How to check for DBNull?

Regards

Tea

Comment: Note that you could use just `tbDuration.Text=MyReader["TDuration"].ToString();` as DBNull.Value converts to an empty string this way.

Comment: now get a Cannot implicitly convert type 'object' to 'string'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`DBNull` is a type.  What you're looking for is a static member on that type: `DBNull.Value`.  Something like this:

```
tbDuration.Text = MyReader["TDuration"] == DBNull.Value ? "" : (string)MyReader["TDuration"];
```

**Note:** You also don't want to cast to a `string` for the purpose of the comparison.  `DBNull.Value` will work for the actual result from `MyReader[]`, but not if you cast it.  After validating that it's not null, then you cast it.

Comment: except for the first cast to string - that will fail for a DBNull.

Comment: Yep now getting a Operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type 'string' and 'System.DBNull'

Answer (score 3):

Use **[DBNull.Value](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dbnull.value.aspx)** for checking for null values.

```
tbDuration.Text = 
MyReader["TDuration"]==DBNull.Value?"":(string)MyReader["TDuration"]
```

Or, you can use:

```
tbDuration.Text = 
DBNull.Value.Equals(MyReader["TDuration"]) ?"":(string)MyReader["TDuration"]
```

Answer (score 1):

You should be checking for [`DBNull.Value`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/system.dbnull.value.aspx), not `DBNull` directly.

Answer (score 0):

**[`System.DbNull.Value`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dbnull.value.aspx)**, is a valid reference to an instance of `System.DbNull`.

So you can check against the static value property of `DBNull`.

So It should be `DbNull.Value` not only `DbNull`

```
(string)MyReader["TDuration"]==DBNull.Value?"":(string)MyReader["TDuration"];
```